# Why there's no answer after I executed my code?

Tags: c++

Here are the codes that I have learned from Youtube, but after I run it, it is blank on the small screen:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
    
int getMin(int num1, int num2) {
    int answer;
    if (num1 < num2) {
        answer = num1;
    } else {
        answer = num2;
    }
    return answer;
}
    
    
int main() {
    getMin(3,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't print the result...

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: YouTube is the singularly worst place to learn C++. I'd strongly advise against it. Get a [good reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) you can depend on to provide *in depth* answers to your questions. C++ is a monster of a programming language, it is not something you can just walk into and pick up one ten minute "tutorial" at a time. If you prefer video, don't forget **free, high quality resources** like [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) exist!

Comment: Thanks for your precious advice @tadman !

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int getMin(int num1, int num2){

 if (num1 < num2)
    return num1;
 else 
   return num2;
 }


 int main (){
     cout<<getMin (3,5); // Result of getmin(3,5)
return 0;
}
```

You're passing the argument to a function that has a return value but when the function is returning the value you're not storing that value anywhere or printing it. You can store that value in a variable and can print directly like in the above code.

Comment: `std::cout << getMin(3,5) << std::endl` also works.

Comment: Yes @tadman It will also work